# ASP.NET MVC Null object returned from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, post, http-post

I have a very simple issue which probably has a very simple answer, however, I cannot work it out.

I have a view model as below:

```
namespace CommunicationsLog.ViewModels
{
    public class CommunicationViewModel
    {
        public Communication Communication { get; set; }
        public Feedback Feedback { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<Resolution> Resolutions { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to create a new instance of a communication from my Add.cshtml page:

```
@model CommunicationsLog.ViewModels.CommunicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Communication"))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="addForm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class="text-danger"})
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Customer.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @if (Model.Communication.Customer.Name == null)
                        {
                            <input id="btnCust" type="button" value="Select Customer" class="btn btn-default addCustomer" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span id="custSpan" style="font-size:16px; font:bold;">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Communication.Customer.Name)
                                <input id="btnEditCust" type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default addCustomer"/>
                            </span>
                        }
                     <div id="addCust"></div>
                 </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Communications", "Index")
</div>
```

On submit this calls the below controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(CommunicationViewModel viewModel)
    {
        callEnd = DateTime.Now;
        var totalCallTime = callEnd - callStart;
        Communication insertedComm = null;
        try
        {
            Communication comm = viewModel.Communication;
            comm.CallTime = totalCallTime.ToString(@"mm\:ss");
            var customer = _uow.CustomerRepository.Get()
                                                .Where(c => c.Name == comm.Customer.Name);
            comm.CustomerId = customer.FirstOrDefault().CustomerId;
            comm.Customer = customer.FirstOrDefault();
            comm.State = "Open";
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                insertedComm = _uow.CommunicationRepository.Insert(comm);
                _uow.Save();

            }

            Feedback feedback = viewModel.Feedback;
            if (feedback.Type != null && feedback.Notes != null)
            {
                feedback.Communication = insertedComm;
                feedback.CommunicationId = insertedComm.CommunicationId;
                var insertedFB = _uow.FeedbackRepository.Insert(feedback);
                _uow.Save();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if(viewModel.Communication == null)
            {
                viewModel.Communication = new Communication();
            }                
            return View(viewModel);
        }
    }
```

However, when the viewModel is loaded to the controller action, the communication object is null. The feedback object is successfully instantiated.

After debugging i have worked out that the view model is instantiated correctly and is not null when the page loads and that is shown by pre defined data displaying correctly. It only seems to lose the value on the POST request.

Can anybody help?

Many Thanks,

EDIT:

As pointed out in comments i have actually removed the important part from my snippet so here is the full view excluding the javascript as that is not relevant for the POST request:

```
@model CommunicationsLog.ViewModels.CommunicationViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Add";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h2>Add</h2>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Add", "Communication"))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal" id="addForm">
        <h4>Communication</h4>
        <div id="countdown" class="countdownHolder"></div>
        <hr/>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class="text-danger"})
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Customer.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @if (Model.Communication.Customer.Name == null)
                        {
                            <input id="btnCust" type="button" value="Select Customer" class="btn btn-default addCustomer" />
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            <span id="custSpan" style="font-size:16px; font:bold;">
                                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Communication.Customer.Name)
                                <input id="btnEditCust" type="button" value="Edit" class="btn btn-default addCustomer"/>
                            </span>
                        }
                        <div id="addCust"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Receiver, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.Receiver, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.Receiver, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.Department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.Department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.CommDateTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <span id="custSpan" style="font-size:14px;">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Communication.CommDateTime)
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Method, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.Method, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.Method, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Product, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.Product, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.Product, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.PartNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.PartNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.PartNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Communication.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.Label("Feedback?", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        <input type="checkbox" id="chkFeedback" name="chkFeedback" onclick="showFeedbackForm(this)"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="feedbackForm" style="display:none">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Feedback.Type, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Feedback.Type, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Feedback.Type, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Feedback.Notes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                        <div class="col-md-10">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Feedback.Notes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Feedback.Notes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to Communications", "Index")
</div>
```

I dont know if it helps but here is the full stack trace from VS:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.       
   at ASP._Page_Views_Communication_Add_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Projects\CommunicationsLog\CommunicationsLog\Views\Communication\Add.cshtml:line 24
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: You are not binding anything back because MVC cannot find anything TO bind back. I see displayfor and labels but where are your inputs?

Comment: Apologies i have updated the question with my full view

Comment: What happens if you remove @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Communication) ?

Comment: Same thing that was one of my attempts to resolve the issue by storing the communication in a hidden field

Comment: Remove it, it doesn't do anything good :)

Comment: As far as i can tell all of the fields in Communication do have a @Html.HiddenFor()

Comment: @Chad: why? If there are already existing values, the editorfor will already contain them?

Comment: The reason i know its an issue with the post by the way is that the CommDateTime and Receiver fields are pre populated and therefore i know that it works fine up until that point

Comment: Why has this been down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using markup, any `<input>` tag needs to have a name defined, the name/value pairs of inputs gets posted back to the server:

```
<input name="@Html.NameFor(i => i.Communication.Customer.Name)" ... />
```

And then the model will be populated.  You could also use:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(i => i.Communication.Customer.Name)
```

All your inputs need this.  I also saw you had the value attribute contain "Select Customer"; this will post back to the server.  If you use `placeholder="Select Customer"`, then this value doesn't get posted to the server, but still shows when the textbox is empty.

Comment: The way that works is, if there is no customer for the communication, then only a button is displayed which loads a dialog box for you to select a customer which then reloads the add view with the correct details (this all works) once the customer is selected, then it displays the name in a displayfor and shows an edit button. so can you clarify which input i need to change and how as currently, the customer name display for isnt in an input. Sorry if im missing something and being naive

Comment: @DaRoGa you aren't being naive; you got a complicated setup here.  I really don't know I understand fully enough to guide you.  But you have to understand the rule that MVC only model binds data it has.  So it uses a convention of mapping the input's name to the model by using the Html.NameFor(i => i.Communication.Customer.Name) helper, which generates something like Communcation__Customer__Name to the client (that's not 100% correct...) and so MVC then uses this convention to rebind a nested model.  MVC doesn't see any inputs like this posted back to the server and thus your model is null.

Comment: Your challenge is to figure out what you need to send to the server when/where, within the form....  I noticed none of your <input> tags didn't have a name attribute, so when a post happens, nothing would be sent to the server on a POST operation....

Comment: Hi @BrianMains. Thanks for that. Sorry about the late reply i have just returned to work. Could you please explain your last point regarding none of the input tags not having a name attribute?My only <input>s are buttons which work fine except for the submit button. Should this button be adapted somehow in order to send the form correctly? Thanks for your help with this

Comment: Well, yes I didn't see all of the markup, and so I was wrong about the input.  In your example above, Feedback will always have a value because you have @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Feedback.Notes), which is rendering an input that the server sees a value for, but nothing for the Communication object.  If there are no inputs/selects for Communication, then it will not send anything back to the server and it will be null.  At least putting something in a hidden field will help.